# How to query database if variables don't always have a value

Tags: php, mysql, geocoding

Right I'm working on a location search element to one of our applications but I'm stuck.

We have four different rows in our database. Address, City, State and ZIP. So when the user adds the address, it will search using one, two, thee or four of those rows.

i.e.

**Search 1:** Fratton Road, Portsmouth, Endland, PO1 3NP
**Search 2:** England
**Search 3:** Liverpool, England

We currently break the search term apart into the four elements, the same as stated above these are $address, $city, $state, $zip.

So the simple query to search IF all four variables have a value is:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM activity WHERE (address=?) AND (city=?) AND (state=?) AND (zip=?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $array['address'], $array['city'], $array['state'], $array['zip']);
$stmt->execute();
```

But what do I do when they don't all have a value? What if the search term is only England or Liverpool England. The ZIP and Address lines have no value thus causing an error.

Should I do a query for each of the four elements. Getting the id's back for address, city, state and zip then remove any duplicates? Or is there a better way?

Cheers for reading.

Comment: You need to conditionally add them to the query. Construct your query and add your bindings to an `array`.

Comment: are they all strings if so i have a solution to do so

Comment: [Null safe equality operator?](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) `WHERE (address <=> ?) AND (city <=> ?)...`

Comment: @MarkBaker I don't think the null safe operator would work in this case as that operator would return a 0/false for the case where the a null value was passed but the value in the DB record was not null.  This means the records would not meat the condition. Unless the OP want a search like `England` to only return cases where the record has `England` for country and null for all other values, this would not work.

Comment: What about changing instead or AND to (OR). That may fix your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up conditionally adding the querys as suggested by tadman. Was hoping that there would be a different way to do it due to the amount of conditions this involved writing. Thanks for all the replies.

Answer (score 0):

One such approach I've used in the past is conditionally in the where clause... something like

```
where ( addressparm = '' OR table.address = addressParm )
  AND ( cityparm = '' or table.city = cityparm )
  AND ( stateparm = '' or table.state = stateparm )
```

Then your query remains the same and will ignore those that do not have a value provided, but as tadman noted, since you are building your query dynamically, you might just add as they are available.

Answer (score 0):

use it like this if the columns are varchars

```
SELECT id FROM activity WHERE (address like '%?%') AND (city like '%?%') AND (state like '%?%') AND (zip like '%?%')
```

if values are there its ok other wise it should do the purpose with wildcard character %

Answer (score 0):

In basic SQL you can use NVL function.
Look here for definition: [mysql.com forum](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?99,59732,59732)

But only in case you have variable in SQL (but I think, this is not working here)
Example for this approach:

```
SELECT id FROM table_a WHERE column_x = NVL(VARIABLE, column_x)
```

If you use this in SQL and VARIABLE will be NULL, then all rows will be returned.

But, I think, better way is to use php for create statement you want.
For example:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM activity WHERE 1=1"
  . ((trim($array['address'])==='')?" AND address='" . $array['address'] . "'":"")
  . ((trim($array['city'])==='')?" AND city='" . $array['city'] . "'":"")
  . ((trim($array['state'])==='')?" AND state='" . $array['state'] . "'":"")
  . ((trim($array['zip'])==='')?" AND zip='" . $array['zip'] . "'":"")
);
```

And don't forget to single quotes around strings. ;)